# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{x}$$
I know the limit is $-1\over3$ by looking at the graph of the function, but how can I algebraically show that that is the limit (without L'Hopital Rule)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Using $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

$$1-x-1=\{(1-x)^{\frac13}-1\}\{(1-x)^{\frac23}+(1-x)^{\frac13}+1\}$$

$$\implies \frac{(1-x)^{\frac13}-1}x=\frac{-x}{x\{(1-x)^{\frac23}+(1-x)^{\frac13}+1\}}$$

Use $x\ne0$ as $x\to0$

Answer (score 6):

HINT :

Letting $1-x=t^3$, then you'll get
$$\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{t-1}{1-t^3}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{t-1}{-(t-1)(t^2+t+1)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Another way to view this, if you have derivatives, but not L'Hospital's Rule, is to observe that for $f(t) = t^{1/3}$, we have that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1 - x)^{1/3} - 1}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(1 - x) - f(1)}{-x} = -f'(1)$. Since we know that $f'(t) = \frac{1}{3}t^{-2/3}$, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

One more way: the numerator can be expanded as Binomial series:
$$
(1-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{3}}{k}(-x)^k-1=1-\frac{x}{3}+O(x^2)-1=-\frac{x}{3}+O(x^2)
$$
from which the result easily follows

Answer (score 0):

Starting from
$$\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}x=\frac{\exp(\frac13\ln(1-x))-1}x,$$
notice that for $x\to0$, we have $\ln(1-x)\sim -x$ and
$\mathrm{e}^{-x/3}-1\sim -\frac x3$. You get immediately the desired result.