# Trouble trying to find asymptoes of $f(x)= \sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm working on a problem where I am trying to find the asymptotes to a function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}$ in the interval of $[-1,\infty)$. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any relevant examples to learn from, and as a result, I am completely stuck.

After drawing the function up in GeoGebra and CAS, the function seems to have the asymptotes $x=-1$, $x=0$, and the slant asymptote $y=x+1/3$.

**My strategy so far has been to use the rule for finding slant asymptotes:**

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ and $b=\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-{x}$)

This has led me to find that $a$ in $y=ax+b$ is equal to $a=1$, which at least is one step in the right direction.

**My problem occurs when I'm trying to find $b$ by using**
$b=\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)= \sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-x $

I have tried to use the chain rule for limits $(b=\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{\frac{1}{3}ln(x^3+x^2)})$ and wirte it as $b=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-x)\cdot(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}+x)}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}+x}$ that I've used in the past to solve similar problems (though with quadratic roots rather than cubic roots)

**In relation to what I just described, my questions are**

1. Is my strategy not the right one? If it is not, can anyone guide me onto a more productive path?
2. If my strategy is adequate. Is there someone out there kind enough to help me solve this problem?

*As mentioned above, $b$ is supposed to be $\frac{1}{3}$*(Given that GeoGebra is correct).

All help is welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

To find $b$ we can use that

$$\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-x= \sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3}$$

and

$$A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)$$

Refer also to the related

- [Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/630282/505767)

---

**Edit**

As an alternative approach, by [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

$$f(x)= \sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}= x \left(1+\frac1x\right)^\frac13=x\left(1+\frac 1{3x}  +O\left(\frac 1{x^2}\right)\right)=\overbrace{x+\frac13}^{\text{asymptote}}+ O\left(\frac 1{x}\right)$$

with $O\left(\frac 1{x}\right)\to 0$ as $x\to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the hints you provided. Much appreciated! Pardon me for being a bit slow (after several hours of battling this problem :-p ), but for some reason, I can´t see how you can make $\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3}$ fit into the sum of two cubes formula$(A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2))$. Don't they need to be raised to the third power in order to apply the 'sum of two cubes' formula?

Comment: @fredericoamigo Let take $A=\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}$ and $B=\sqrt[3]{x^3}$.